# File Browser filter bar

Tags: interface, file-browser

I keep seeing this filter / view options bar in Blender's File Browser, in different videos and even on [the manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/_images/editors_file-browser_previews.png), but can't find a way to activate it. Or is it an addon?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The filter options are in the dropdown menu right next to the filter icon on the top right. The  of the main menu entries *File > Link...* and *File > Append ...* also have an *Advanced Filter* section on the left side.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes, but that doesn't display the bar as shown on the screenshot

Comment: Things change over time ;-) [Blender 2.80](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) looks like your screenshot. Blender 3.3 looks like my screenshot.

Comment: uhmm yeah, that's correct..... imho that's a bad design decision. They should've at least left an option to re-enable it.